# How can i send the command Argument value of linkbutton on mouseover of link button to c# webmethod?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, json.net, webmethod

I want to send the command Argument value of linkbutton on mouseover of it to the c# webmethod via Json. Is it possible? How? This how i am trying but it is not working:
aspx code:

```
 <asp:LinkButton Text='<%#Eval("SNA")%>' ID="lnkpro1" runat="server" CssClass="linkbutton"
                                                        OnClick="btn_Click1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Code") %>' onmouseover="return get();" ToolTip='<%# Eval("code") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

json:

```
functionget(e) {
     var Code= e.title; 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/MyMethod",
            data: "{'Code':'" + code+ "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {





            }
        });

    }
```

C# webmethod:

```
public static List<string>   Records(string code)
    {

        List<string> getrecords = new List<string>();

        return getrecords;
    }
```

web method is not hitting onmouseover of linkbutton if i write tooltip but it is the only way i am thinking by which i can send the command argument of link button to c# method. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace you onmouseover="return get();" with following

```
onmouseover='<%# "return get(" + Eval("code") + ");" %>'
```

and in java script get function get code as argument like following

```
function get(strcode){

// pass this strcode in you ajax parameter 
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/MyMethod",
        data: "{'Code':'" + strcode + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {





        }
    });
}
```

Comment: web method is not working onmouseover of linkbutton. Tried with using debugger.

Comment: put alert to check strcode value in java script function if it is well the we can check further that what is wrong in you ajax code

Comment: can you tell me i have a employee id in session . How to access it in webmethod?

Comment: change your [WebMethod] attribute with [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] then use session like you use in page

Comment: this error is coming when i enable the session in webmethod as you say: Error 15 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Session.get'

Comment: use like HttpContext.Current.Session["empid"]